# Changing the order in data.table R

Tags: r, data.table

I have a file with two columns: 1) Gene names(Symbol) 2) Entrez ID.
I read it and then convert it to data.table by:

```
names_DT <- data.table(Symbol=names[,1], Entrez=names[,2])
```

then I am fetching some IDs using the below instruction and get the result:

```
names_DT[Entrez==c("2597","3945", "6222", "2597"),]
   Symbol Entrez
1:  GAPDH   2597
2:  GAPDH   2597
3:   LDHB   3945
4:  RPS18   6222
```

As you can see the order of result does not match the input?!!
I really need the order of result be matched to the input. Am I missed something?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for `%in%` instead of `==`? I'm surprised this even worked or at least didn't return a warning. Can you show us `names_DT`

Comment: @DavidArenburg The bellow link contains my table, "names". [https://www.dropbox.com/s/sbijdvloz89oj0m/geneSymb_Entrez.RData?dl=0]
Please just run the mentioned instruction.

Comment: When I'm running your code I'm getting the expected error, while the suggested solution (kindly provided by the `data.table` devs) is to use `%in%` instead. Just like I said in my first comment. So I don't understand where you getting the result from. The code should be `names_DT[Entrez %in% c("2597","3945", "6222", "2597")]`

Comment: @DavidArenburg I get the previous result, again! 
Did you run the code on the file I put its link in previous comment?

Comment: Yes I did. What `data.table` version are you using?

Comment: @DavidArenburg It is data.table_1.9.4. You get different result?

Comment: Try installing the devel version on GH maybe

Comment: Did it fix it? You can also do `options(datatable.auto.index = FALSE)` and then try your code again. My guess it will fail, while `names_DT[Entrez %in% c("2597","3945", "6222", "2597")]` will work correctly.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I just ran OP's code and it, surprisingly, worked without the `%in%` syntax.  I'm running R 3.2 with DT 1.9.4

Comment: @Dean did you see my last comment?

Comment: @DavidArenburg 

The weird thing is that the below code works well:

names <- matrix(c("A","1","B","2","C","3","D","4"),ncol=2,byrow=T)

names_DT <- data.table(Symbol=names[,1], Entrez=names[,2])

names_DT[Symbol==c("D","A","B","A"),]

while it does not work for my data?!

Comment: Now really, did any of you try `options(datatable.auto.index = FALSE)` or not?

Comment: @DavidArenburg
I ran it, it does not work! I get the below output:

Empty data.table (0 rows) of 2 cols: Symbol,Entrez
Warning message:
In Entrez == c("2597", "3945", "6222", "2597") :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Comment: Yes, that it what supposed to happen. It means it does work. now do `names_DT[Entrez %in% c("2597","3945", "6222", "2597")]`

Comment: @DavidArenburg
I tried it; I get this:  

`Symbol Entrez
1:  GAPDH   2597
2:   LDHB   3945
3:  RPS18   6222`

This is not what I want.

Comment: Yes. That is *exactly* what you should get. It doesn't matter what you want or not. This is the *truth*. The truth isn't effected by your will.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Can I ask you to run these instructions:
`names <- matrix(c("A","1","B","2","C","3","D","4"),ncol=2,byrow=T) names_DT <- data.table(Symbol=names[,1], Entrez=names[,2]) names_DT[Symbol==c("D","A","B","A"),]`

I want an output like this!

Comment: Ok, I'm trying to tell you for some time now, `names_DT[Symbol==c("D","A","B","A"),]` incorrect syntax. The syntax should be `names_DT[Symbol %in% c("D","A","B","A"),]`.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I didn't realize the auto.index was the reason for the difference in behavior.  I just thought it was weird that OP's syntax "worked".  Moving completely away from OP's situation, is there a general use benefit to having auto.index set to FALSE?

Comment: @DeanMacGregor it is an bug that was fixed in the devel version. This is why I recommended to try it in my previous comments.

Comment: @DavidArenburg If I'm not mistaken, having `%in% c("D","A","B","A")` is the same as `%in% c("D","A","B") so to get this to output like OP wants they'd have to do something hacky like I have in my answer right?

Comment: @DavidArenburg just to make sure we're on the same page, when you say "error that was fixed in devel version", you're referring to OP's incorrect `==` syntax "working" instead of throwing an error as *the* error?

Comment: @DeanMacGregor I have no idea what the OP wants anymore, all I wanted to say is that 1- this is an error. 2- `==` in not the correct syntax.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor yes. It had some additional errors that were also fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this use case was ever considered when the smart people were making data.table.  I think the result it is providing is what 99.9% of what users would want.  Here is a hack that will get you the order you want.

```
merge(data.table(Entrez=c("2597","3945", "6222", "2597"),order=1:4),names_DT,all.x=TRUE,by="Entrez")[order(order),list(Entrez,Symbol)]
```

Basically what this does is forces the order you want by making your query into a new data.table with an order column.  You then merge that data.table to your data and specify that the output be ordered by the order column that you created in the first step.

Comment: The below code works well:
`names <- matrix(c("A","1","B","2","C","3","D","4"),ncol=2,byrow=T) names_DT <- data.table(Symbol=names[,1], Entrez=names[,2]) names_DT[Symbol==c("D","A","B","A"),]`

while it does not work for my data?!

Comment: @user4704857 you need to use `%in%` instead of `==` for starters.